# MxToolBox Email deliverability SSL connect error

Tags: postfix, ubuntu-16.04

I have set a mail server using postfix, and I can send and receive email, I have certificate created from letsencrypt, but when I try to test the email from this tool:

http://mxtoolbox.com/deliverability

In the mail log I see a lot of error:

```
postfix/smtp[15352]: SSL_connect error to mx1.tools.mxtoolbox.com[208.123.79.38]:25: -1
warning: TLS library problem: error:1407741A:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert decode error:s23_clnt.c:769:
9489F3A12F: Cannot start TLS: handshake failure
```

anyone know how can I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How is your mail server configured?

Comment: What you want know?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?